# Shortcuts for subscript and superscript Word 2016, Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Word 2016 on a macbook air with a danish keyboard. The manual states that

> Superscript: Command + Shift + Plus Sign
>
> Subscript: Command + Equal Sign

However when I pres `Command + Plus Sign` it creates subscript. However no key-combination gives superscript - any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is `plus` above `equals` on that keyboard? That's what it's expecting, so super is 'shifted' sub.

Answer (score 0):

The key combinations work fine with English keyboard layout - make sure that when you use Danish that the mapping is the same for the plus and equal signs. I tested with CZ layout and I had to remap the + sign to a new key in order for the superscript to work